# assignment in JS

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

This is a very basic JS question, but this "issue" drives me crazy.

From simple algebra I would expect that both first and the second statement are vaild. But the second is always throwing "Invalid assignment" error.

Does anyone have a good explanation for it?

```
fieldname1 = document.getElementById("emailID1");
document.getElementById("emailID2") = fieldname2;
```

Thanks so much,

Comment: Hello Lídia, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can not assign value to a function.

Comment: `document.getElementById(...)` returns an *element*, that is an object that contains many fields and data-members (as well as a set of functions). What is the purpose of assigning to the element?

Comment: You are assigning the fieldname2 wrong way.

Comment: Hello Ivan, thanks! The code was just an example about the difference Between  

"variablename = document.blablabla" 
and 
"document.blablabla = variablename"

Comment: It's a bit of unfortunate history in programming languages that `=` has so often been used as an assignment operator. It probably would have saved a lot of confusion over many, many years if `=` was only ever used for comparison. Some languages (like Pascal) use `:=` instead. I think I would have preferred that `←` had been a basic ASCII character, and became the established assignment operator.

Answer (score 3):

Most common programming languages, including JavaScript, require that the left-hand side of an assignment (the "target") be something called an *l-value*.  That means it's an expression that denotes a place to put a value. A simple variable name, or a reference to an object followed by `.propertyName` suffix, works as an *l-value*.

In your case, the function call return value is *not* an *l-value*, because JavaScript does not make that possible (some languages do). A function call is always an *r-value*, meaning something that appears on the right-hand side of an assignment.

Now, in your particular case, because `getElementById()` returns a reference to a DOM element, you can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("something").name = "frederick";
```

The function still returns an *r-value*, but that `.name` works as a property reference and thus as an *l-value*.

Comment: I realize that this simplifies the nuances of assignment expressions.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you so much! this is the answer I was looking for! :D

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operator resolves the right side of the equal sign and stores it in the variable on the left side, which is what is happening in the first line.

The second line is basically trying to take the value of a variable `fieldname2` and store it in a function call `document.getElementById("emailID2")`

JavaScript doesn't know how to resolve that at runtime, so it's throwing an invalid assignment operation.

There's more information on assignment from MDN here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to an object itself in this case.

```
document.getElementById("emailID2") = fieldname2;
```

As i guess you want to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("emailID2").name = fieldname2;
```